# Mathematica return no solution just empty brackets {}

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve continuous time markov chain. as the chain became big mathematica stops solving it. equation i tried to solve is as under. the output should be steady state probabilities of different states in form of \pi subscript from a to l. the answer i get is empty {}. no error.  much appreciate the help in advance.

[image]

```
Solve[{Subscript[π, 
    a] (Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[λ, l] + 
      Subscript[λ, h]) == 
   Subscript[π, b] Subscript[μ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, d] Subscript[μ, l] + 
    Subscript[π, e] Subscript[μ, h],
  Subscript[π, 
    b] (Subscript[μ, p] + Subscript[λ, l] + 
      Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[λ, h]) == 
   Subscript[π, a] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, c] Subscript[μ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, g] Subscript[μ, lu] + 
    Subscript[π, h] Subscript[μ, hu],
  Subscript[π, 
    c] (Subscript[λ, h] + Subscript[μ, p] + 
      Subscript[λ, l]) == 
   Subscript[π, b] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, j] Subscript[μ, lu] + 
    Subscript[π, k] Subscript[μ, hu],
  Subscript[π, 
    d] (Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[μ, l] + 
      Subscript[λ, h]) == 
   Subscript[π, a] Subscript[λ, l] + 
    Subscript[π, f] Subscript[μ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, g] Subscript[μ, p],
  Subscript[π, 
    e] (Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[λ, l] + 
      Subscript[μ, hu]) == 
   Subscript[π, a] Subscript[λ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, f] Subscript[μ, lu] + 
    Subscript[π, h] Subscript[μ, p],
  Subscript[π, 
    f] (Subscript[μ, h] + Subscript[μ, lu] + 
      Subscript[λ, p]) == 
   Subscript[π, d] Subscript[λ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, e] Subscript[λ, l] + 
    Subscript[π, i] Subscript[μ, c],
  Subscript[π, 
    g] (Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[λ, h] + 
      Subscript[μ, p] + Subscript[μ, lu]) == 
   Subscript[π, b] Subscript[λ, l] + 
    Subscript[π, d] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, i] Subscript[μ, hu] + 
    Subscript[π, j] Subscript[μ, p],
  Subscript[π, 
    h] (Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[λ, l] + 
      Subscript[μ, p] + Subscript[μ, lu]) == 
   Subscript[π, b] Subscript[λ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, e] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, k] Subscript[μ, p],
  Subscript[π, 
    i] (Subscript[λ, p] + Subscript[μ, p] + 
      Subscript[μ, hu]) == 
   Subscript[π, f] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, g] Subscript[λ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, h] Subscript[λ, l] + 
    Subscript[π, l] Subscript[μ, p],
  Subscript[π, 
    j] (Subscript[λ, h] + Subscript[μ, p] + 
      Subscript[μ, lu]) == 
   Subscript[π, c] Subscript[λ, l] + 
    Subscript[π, g] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, l] Subscript[μ, hu],
  Subscript[π, 
    k] (Subscript[λ, l] + Subscript[μ, p] + 
      Subscript[μ, hu]) == 
   Subscript[π, c] Subscript[λ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, h] Subscript[λ, p],
  Subscript[π, l] (Subscript[μ, p] + Subscript[μ, hu]) == 
   Subscript[π, i] Subscript[λ, p] + 
    Subscript[π, j] Subscript[λ, h] + 
    Subscript[π, k] Subscript[λ, l],
  Subscript[π, a] + Subscript[π, b] + Subscript[π, c] + 
    Subscript[π, d] + Subscript[π, e] + Subscript[π, f] + 
    Subscript[π, g] + Subscript[π, h] + Subscript[π, i] + 
    Subscript[π, j] + Subscript[π, k] + Subscript[π, l] ==
    1}, {Subscript[π, a], Subscript[π, b], Subscript[π, 
  c] , Subscript[π, d], Subscript[π, e], Subscript[π, f], 
  Subscript[π, g], Subscript[π, h], Subscript[π, i], 
  Subscript[π, j], Subscript[π, k], Subscript[π, l]}]
```

Comment: its the upgrade of my previous work where i solved it for 8 variables of pi and it gave values. i double checked it  and i am sure there is no syntax or derivation error in system.

Comment: Try `FindInstance` with respect to all the variables.

Comment: Are you sure that the equations describe a "normal" Markov chain? For that, the transition probabilities should add up to 1, which is clearly not the case here. And without that, I am not surprised that there is no general solution, since there is no reason for the total of all state variables to stay constant. (i.e. any non-zero state will most likely decay to 0 or explode to infinity)

Comment: Thanks @LukasLang for pointing me to right direction